# How to retrieve the size of a specific stream before doing sync

Tags: perforce

I'm working on a script and need to query the size of a specific stream before I do a sync to a local harddrive. The local unsynced folder is empty.
I know there is a p4 sizes and I have tried the following command

```
p4 -u TheUserName -p ExternalServerUrl -c MyWorkspace sizes -s //Path/To/Stream -H
```

But it seems to report my local storage (which is empty).
So the output I get is this:

```
//Path/To/Stream 0 files 0 bytes
-H 0 files 0 bytes
```

So how can I query the server for the size before actually doing the sync?

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use wildcards to refer to a set of multiple files (including a depot directory path):

```
p4 sizes -s -H //Path/To/Stream/...
```

Note that if the `-H` goes after the file path, it's treated as another file path, which is why your output included the line `-H 0 files 0 bytes`.

Another important thing to note is that the depot path corresponding to the stream name is not necessarily the same thing as the stream contents -- if the stream is a virtual stream, or if it has `import` paths, some or all of its files live under other depot paths.  For your purposes you probably want to instead use a client-path syntax, which will correspond to everything in the workspace (i.e. everything mapped by the workspace's stream):

```
p4 sizes -s -H //MyClient/...
```

The other solution, which will also work if the local directory isn't empty, is to take advantage of the `totalFileSize` field in the tagged output of `p4 sync`:

```
p4 -Ztag -F "%totalFileSize% bytes (%totalFileCount% files)" sync -n -q
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :-) When I have enough points I'll up your post.